# PHP contact form is not echoing the information

Tags: php, contact-form

I really know nothing of PHP. I'm using this template contact form which works.....but when I receive the email, the entered information on the form is not in the email. Am I missing something? 
thanks

```
<?php

    /* Email Variables */
    $emailSubject = 'New Email Subscriber'; /*Make sure this matches the name of your file*/
    $webMaster = 'greg@flymedia.ca';

    /*design by Mark Leroy @ http://www.helpvid.net*/

    /* Data Variables */
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];



    $body = <<<EOD
    <br><hr><br>
    Name: $name <br>
    Email: $email <br>
    EOD;
    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body,
    $headers);


    /* Results rendered as HTML */
    $theResults = <<<EOD
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>sent message</title>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL=http://www.chapswings.com/newsite">
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    body {
    background-color: #000;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fec001;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-top: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 800px;
    }
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <div align="center">Thank you! Your email has been successfully submitted</div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    EOD;
    echo "$theResults";
    ?>

<form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="form-processing.php">
    <p  style="=padding:0; margin:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;size:10px;">
      <label>Name:<br />
        <input name="Name" type="text" id="FName" size="25" />
      </label>
    </p>
    <p  style="=padding:0; margin:0; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;size:10px;">
      <label>Email:<br />
        <input name="Email" type="text" id="Email" size="25" />
      </label>
    </p>

    <p>
      <label>
        <input name="button" type="submit" class="submit-button" id="button" value="Send" />
      </label>
    </p>
  </form>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML of your form

Comment: Debating on whether I should put this as an "answer" --- You can't have any space before or after `EOD;` and you have four "before" `EOD;`. Least, in your posted code.

Comment: I have edited and posted my HTML

Comment: Letter-case is important for POST variables. @Greg as noted in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$email = $_POST['Email'];
$name = $_POST['Name'];
```

The indexes/keys are case-sensitive

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong.

First as I said, no spaces before or after `EOD;` **heredocs** are funny that way (in case there are any, and there are some in your posted code) so I thought I would make a note about that, just in case.

And your form inputs are called `name="Name"` and `name="Email"` yet your `$_POST` variables are:

```
$email = $_POST['email']; // notice the lowercase "e"
$name = $_POST['name']; // notice the lowercase "n"
```

You need to change that to:

`name="name"` and `name="email"` or make the appropriate changes to your `$_POST` variables.

- **Those are case-sensitive.**